# What role do SCA SuiteScript files execute as?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitecommerce

What role do all the .SSP files execute under in SuiteCommerce Advance Mont Blanc? Is it `Customer Center`?

**Context:**
My SuiteScript file `Account/SuiteScript/Account.Model.js` retrieves information from the `Customer` database table. But its failing/crashing because the script/file doesn't have permission to view the `Customer` database.

```
// Crash occurs here. (Inside login function)
var picSearch = nlapiSearchRecord('customer', null, 
        new nlobjSearchFilter('custentity_bd_carer', null, 'is', ''+profile.internalid));
```

So I need to know which role the script is executing under and then edit that roles permissions to be allowed to view the `Customer` table.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct in using the 'Customer Center' role although a non logged in customer uses the 'Shopper' role.

To quote from the docs:

---

### ROLES

There are two NetSuite roles used in the context of Web Stores:

Shopper Role
Customer Center Role

### SHOPPER ROLE

A shopper role indicates a user who is not authenticated and does not have a customer role. Anytime a user visits a web site, that user's session is assigned a shopper role by default when no other role has been established by a prior login in this session.

A Shopper role is a role in NetSuite that has no write permissions and read-only permissions to limited record types in the account, such as items. With a shopper role, users can not take any action that would create a new record, other than registering as a customer.

NOTE As a direct result of how the Shopper role is used in SuiteCommerce Advanced sites, some functionality is not currently supported. For example, we currently do not support the newsletter functionality in SuiteCommerce Advanced sites since a user with a Shopper role can not directly create a new lead record.

### CUSTOMER CENTER ROLE

The Customer Center role provides elevated permissions to records, such as transactions, that are required to create the Checkout and My Account experiences. This role can be customized to adjust the level of access. For example, you can remove links to transactions or records or limit access to only viewing instead of editing or creating records.

---

If you're only looking to retrive data from the Customer record who'se logged in, you should be able to use customer.getCustomFieldValues() or customer.getFieldValues(). See https://youtu.be/gxSxZBVjKZY?t=1052 published by NetSuite.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, in File Cabinet, you can look at the *.ss files for SCA, in Edit mode, under Role's, you can specify which role you wish to execute the *.ss file as.

So therefore, you can restrict or grant more permissions for the application to have. Useful for things like contact forms, etc.